# How to Enhance xinit?

Tags: installation, xorg, window-manager

I started with Ubuntu 12.04 minimal and added a couple of applications via apt.

Since these applications require GUI, I used `sudo apt-get install xinit` 
And to start the applications I am doing `startx application-name`

Now I am facing few problems:

- Not having a proper mouse pointer. Just have a "cross" instead.
- Key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is not working; I cannot switch b/w open windows.
- The windows are not having **minimize, maximize, close** buttons.
- PS2 mouse works well, however **USB mouse** is not being detected.
- The System does not **output the sound**. (Videos on youtube runs but w/o sound).
- OPTIONAL: I am also looking for a way out to use mouse keys, i.e control mouse pointer using "Keyboard Numeric Pad

May someone please suggest me what all I need to install to rectify these issues.

PS: Since I require more of a server environment, I am not willing to install a Desktop manager.

Comment: Why exactly are you watching youtube on a server?

Comment: Unrelated:  For the mouse, do you get anything if you tailf /var/log/kern.log and plug in the mouse?  That would tell us whether it was at least picking up the usb device.

Comment: @Darael This is the only system in hand.. Its server for personal use, thus I can go for some personal tasks over it... I am looking for generic sound drivers.. Since when i boot up with a live CD, i get the sound. This install is from minimal..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be willing to install a full desktop *environment*, but in order to get window decorations (including window controls) and the ability to switch between windows, you will still need a *window manager*.  A good WM should help give you a nice cursor, too.

There are all sorts of lightweight window managers out there: fluxbox, openbox, and similar are very light indeed, but you may also want to look at Enlightenment, which is not quite as light but *extremely* full-featured.

I am not entirely sure about your sound problem, but the place to start looking would be ALSA packages.  At a guess, you'll need at least alsa-base and alsa-utils.  You may also need some pulseaudio stuff and/or alsa-oss; I forget which framework the Flash player uses.

Comment: isn't their any way out to use alt+tab functionality beside this?

Comment: That's window management too, which is not done by X, so you need to install a window manager.

Comment: Some of the various window managers are very light indeed - but you can't get your alt+tabbing without one.  EDIT: edited original for further info on sound.

Comment: @Darael If i add metacity, will it serve the purpose? how can i achieve mouse-keys and sound functionality. if i pull up google-chrome via xinitrc i never get sound, everything else works fine

Comment: @Z9iT If you add metacity, you'll get window-management, which will certainly provide alt-tabbing, the ability to raise windows, &c., and possibly mouse-keys, though I'm not sure about that bit.  You won't get sound from metacity - as mentioned in the answer, you'll want to look at ALSA packages.  In addition, if you really want lightweight, you should seriously consider using *box (fluxbox, openbox...) rather than metacity.

Comment: @Darael metacity holds true for me.. i want lightweight, but still i have extented resources to compromize with.. will i be able to achieve the same if i use nautilus instead of metacity?

The sound is still the problem even i have installed alsa and everything which is suggested by apt-get. on some other system i am starting with minimal (not server) and facing the same sound problem. this is the link to this specific question http://askubuntu.com/questions/155740/no-audio-in-google-chrome

Comment: Nautilus is _not_ a window manager, but a file manager.  What you need is a window manager.  I don't know what exactly you need to do about sound, I'm afraid.