# Poor Chrome performance in minimal xsession

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, performance

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed, and I'm trying to create a minimal Chrome browser only setup, and have tried adding our script that runs google-chrome to .xinitrc and running startx (this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/141169/189765)

I'm experiencing significantly worse performance in Chrome (framerates on animations, etc) than when I run the browser from within gnome in Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm trying to understand the difference in performance. Is gnome allowing Chrome to use the video card / GPU in some way, and we're losing this benefit in the standalone xsession?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like problem was solved by updating Nvida drivers & xorg.conf. This worked:

1. Run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
   nvidia-xconfig
   ```
2. Reboot into command line.
3. After starting X, chrome performance was as good as when running in Gnome.